# What areas in Shanghai are quickly commutable to Zubei (Shanghai Station)

Tags: shanghai

I will be spending some time in Shanghai, and will often go to my office in Zubei which is near the Shanghai Railway Station. Since I heard it is not a great area, which areas in Shanghai can one stay in which are an easy commute away? (Say less than 30 minutes)

Comment: Hi, your question mostly concerns expatriates, not travellers. As per the faq, this question will be considered off-topic. Also, it is a bit broad as you do not specify how you want to commute. Car, bike, public transit, helicopter? Words as "easy" or "best" are usually considered subjective (some would not consider easy to walk 30 mins).

Comment: Given the traffic condition in Shanghai, I believe Metro (subway) is the easiest transportation if you don't want to walk too much. Metro #1, #3 and #4 all stop at Shanghai Railway Station. For #1, trains come every 2~3min, each stop takes around 2.5 min. Interval between #3 trains is longer, for #4 it's the longest. Then you can do math: say you want to travel for less than 30 min, then subtract the metro waiting time (2min) and walking time to office. You'll get the time of traveling by Metro, and then you'll know how many stops there would be, and you'll know where you are going to live.

Comment: @Vince Now I am more familiar with the site, I would agree. Ultimately it is an expat rather than a tourist question.